nav2 fluctuating cmd_vel
I am using nav2 with a physical robot, and every once in a while it gets stuck in place where the theta velocity is fluctuating near 0:
linear:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.021052631578947364
---
linear:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: -0.02105263157894737

It stays in place for a while, then the navigation fails.
I am using an external localization, and the sensor source is LaserScan.
I tried to play with the parameters with no avail.
these are the parameters:
bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odom
    enable_groot_monitoring: True
    groot_zmq_publisher_port: 1666
    groot_zmq_server_port: 1667
    default_bt_xml_filename: "navigate_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml"
    plugin_lib_names:
    - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
    - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
    - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
    - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
    - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
    - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
    - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
    - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
    - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
    - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node

bt_navigator_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugin: "goal_checker"
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.2 #0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 20.0 #10.0
    # Goal checker parameters
    goal_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.30 #0.20 #0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25 #0.15 #0.5 #0.25
      stateful: True
    # DWB parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: 0.0
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 0.14
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 0.4
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 0.14
      min_speed_theta: 0.2

      # Add high threshold velocity for turtlebot 3 issue.
      # https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/issues/75
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 9.0 #3.2
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -3.0 #-3.2
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 5
      vtheta_samples: 20
      sim_time: 1.7
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist", "PreferForwardCritic"]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.18 #0.02
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0
      PreferForwardCritic.penalty: 0.1 #18.0 #15.0 #10.0
      PreferForwardCritic.strafe_x: 0.1 #0.08
      #PreferForwardCritic.scale: 100


controller_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 3.0 #5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: False
      rolling_window: True
      width: 3
      height: 3
      resolution: 0.05
#      footprint: "[ [0.2, 0.18], [0.2, -0.18], [-0.16, -0.18], [-0.16, 0.18] ]"
      footprint: "[ [0.18, 0.16], [0.18, -0.16], [-0.14, -0.16], [-0.14, 0.16] ]"

      #robot_radius: 0.21 #0.23 #0.18 #0.209 is real size
      plugins: ["static_layer", "inflation_layer", "obstacle_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 10.0 #3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.7 #1.75 #0.3
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          obstacle_max_range: 1.95
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
          raytrace_max_range: 2.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          max_obstacle_height: 0.4
          min_obstacle_height: 0.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          inf_is_valid: False
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
        enabled: False
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  local_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: False
#      robot_radius: 0.22 #0.23 #0.18 #0.209 is real size
#      footprint: "[ [0.2, 0.18], [0.2, -0.18], [-0.16, -0.18], [-0.16, 0.18] ]"

      footprint: "[ [0.18, 0.16], [0.18, -0.16], [-0.14, -0.16], [-0.14, 0.16] ]"

      resolution: 0.05
      rolling_window: True
      width: 20
      height: 20
      track_unknown_space: False
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          obstacle_max_range: 1.95
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
          raytrace_max_range: 2.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          max_obstacle_height: 0.4
          min_obstacle_height: 0.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          inf_is_valid: False
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
        enabled: False
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 10.0 #3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.7 #1.75 #0.3
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    yaml_filename: "turtlebot3_world.yaml"

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    save_map_timeout: 5000
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: False

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    use_sim_time: False
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      tolerance: 0.5
      use_astar: true
      allow_unknown: true

#      plugin: "smac_planner/SmacPlanner2D" # In Iron and older versions, "/" was used instead of "::"
#      tolerance: 0.125                      # tolerance for planning if unable to reach exact pose, in meters
#      downsample_costmap: false             # whether or not to downsample the map
#      downsampling_factor: 1                # multiplier for the resolution of the costmap layer (e.g. 2 on a 5cm costmap would be 10cm)
#      allow_unknown: true                   # allow traveling in unknown space
#      max_iterations: 1000000               # maximum total iterations to search for before failing (in case unreachable), set to -1 to disable
#      max_on_approach_iterations: 1000      # maximum number of iterations to attempt to reach goal once in tolerance
#      max_planning_time: 2.0                # max time in s for planner to plan, smooth
#      cost_travel_multiplier: 6.0           # Cost multiplier to apply to search to steer away from high cost areas. Larger values will place in the center of aisles more exactly (if non-`FREE` cost potential field exists) but take slightly longer to compute. To optimize for speed, a value of 1.0 is reasonable. A reasonable tradeoff value is 2.0. A value of 0.0 effective disables steering away from obstacles and acts like a naive binary search A*.
#      use_final_approach_orientation: false # Whether to set the final path pose at the goal's orientation to the requested orientation (false) or in line with the approach angle so the robot doesn't rotate to heading (true)
#      smoother:
#        max_iterations: 1000
#        w_smooth: 0.3
#        w_data: 0.2
#        tolerance: 1.0e-10
    
    


planner_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

recoveries_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    recovery_plugins: ["spin", "back_up", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Spin"
    back_up:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/BackUp"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Wait"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_timeout: 5.0 # 0.1
    use_sim_time: false
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.0
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

What might be the solution? I am using nav2 with a physical robot, and every once in a while it gets stuck in place where the theta velocity is fluctuating near 0:

linear:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.021052631578947364
---
linear:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: -0.02105263157894737

It stays in place for a while, then the navigation fails.
I am using an external localization, and the sensor source is LaserScan.
I tried to play with the parameters with no avail.
these are the parameters:

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odom
    enable_groot_monitoring: True
    groot_zmq_publisher_port: 1666
    groot_zmq_server_port: 1667
    default_bt_xml_filename: "navigate_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml"
    plugin_lib_names:
    - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
    - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
    - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
    - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
    - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
    - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
    - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
    - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
    - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
    - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node

bt_navigator_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugin: "goal_checker"
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.2 #0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 20.0 #10.0
    # Goal checker parameters
    goal_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.30 #0.20 #0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25 #0.15 #0.5 #0.25
      stateful: True
    # DWB parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: 0.0
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 0.14
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 0.4
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 0.14
      min_speed_theta: 0.2

      # Add high threshold velocity for turtlebot 3 issue.
      # https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/issues/75
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 9.0 #3.2
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -3.0 #-3.2
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 5
      vtheta_samples: 20
      sim_time: 1.7
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist", "PreferForwardCritic"]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.18 #0.02
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0
      PreferForwardCritic.penalty: 0.1 #18.0 #15.0 #10.0
      PreferForwardCritic.strafe_x: 0.1 #0.08
      #PreferForwardCritic.scale: 100


controller_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 3.0 #5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: False
      rolling_window: True
      width: 3
      height: 3
      resolution: 0.05
#      footprint: "[ [0.2, 0.18], [0.2, -0.18], [-0.16, -0.18], [-0.16, 0.18] ]"
      footprint: "[ [0.18, 0.16], [0.18, -0.16], [-0.14, -0.16], [-0.14, 0.16] ]"

      #robot_radius: 0.21 #0.23 #0.18 #0.209 is real size
      plugins: ["static_layer", "inflation_layer", "obstacle_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 10.0 #3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.7 #1.75 #0.3
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          obstacle_max_range: 1.95
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
          raytrace_max_range: 2.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          max_obstacle_height: 0.4
          min_obstacle_height: 0.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          inf_is_valid: False
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
        enabled: False
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  local_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: False
#      robot_radius: 0.22 #0.23 #0.18 #0.209 is real size
#      footprint: "[ [0.2, 0.18], [0.2, -0.18], [-0.16, -0.18], [-0.16, 0.18] ]"

      footprint: "[ [0.18, 0.16], [0.18, -0.16], [-0.14, -0.16], [-0.14, 0.16] ]"

      resolution: 0.05
      rolling_window: True
      width: 20
      height: 20
      track_unknown_space: False
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          obstacle_max_range: 1.95
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
          raytrace_max_range: 2.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          max_obstacle_height: 0.4
          min_obstacle_height: 0.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          inf_is_valid: False
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
        enabled: False
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 10.0 #3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.7 #1.75 #0.3
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    yaml_filename: "turtlebot3_world.yaml"

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    save_map_timeout: 5000
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: False

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    use_sim_time: False
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      tolerance: 0.5
      use_astar: true
      allow_unknown: true

#      plugin: "smac_planner/SmacPlanner2D" # In Iron and older versions, "/" was used instead of "::"
#      tolerance: 0.125                      # tolerance for planning if unable to reach exact pose, in meters
#      downsample_costmap: false             # whether or not to downsample the map
#      downsampling_factor: 1                # multiplier for the resolution of the costmap layer (e.g. 2 on a 5cm costmap would be 10cm)
#      allow_unknown: true                   # allow traveling in unknown space
#      max_iterations: 1000000               # maximum total iterations to search for before failing (in case unreachable), set to -1 to disable
#      max_on_approach_iterations: 1000      # maximum number of iterations to attempt to reach goal once in tolerance
#      max_planning_time: 2.0                # max time in s for planner to plan, smooth
#      cost_travel_multiplier: 6.0           # Cost multiplier to apply to search to steer away from high cost areas. Larger values will place in the center of aisles more exactly (if non-`FREE` cost potential field exists) but take slightly longer to compute. To optimize for speed, a value of 1.0 is reasonable. A reasonable tradeoff value is 2.0. A value of 0.0 effective disables steering away from obstacles and acts like a naive binary search A*.
#      use_final_approach_orientation: false # Whether to set the final path pose at the goal's orientation to the requested orientation (false) or in line with the approach angle so the robot doesn't rotate to heading (true)
#      smoother:
#        max_iterations: 1000
#        w_smooth: 0.3
#        w_data: 0.2
#        tolerance: 1.0e-10
    
    


planner_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

recoveries_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    recovery_plugins: ["spin", "back_up", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Spin"
    back_up:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/BackUp"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Wait"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_timeout: 5.0 # 0.1
    use_sim_time: false
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.0
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

What might be the solution?
